# finish() not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-finish

In my app, whenever calling the finish() method, wherever it was, I am not taken to the previous activity, rather I am directed to mainActivity.

```
finish();
```

My aim is, showing the user the activity just before the current activity he is seeing.

***Question 1 :*** How can I make finish() always take me to the activity before ?

***Question 2 :*** Does this work using another workaround other than finish() ?

***Question 3 :*** How to check the stack of activities and decide accordingly which one to go to ?

Comment: @No_Rulz. This is mainly a generic question

Comment: did you use onStop(), onPause state.. We can't fix this issue by having the single line

Comment: I guess your are removing the previous activity from stack i.e finishing it before starting new activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written finish in each intermediate activity, that means you are removing the activity from the stack, hence on finishing an activity you are taken to the last non-finished activity, hence write finish() in only that activity which you do not want to see until the same workflow is followed and its onCreate() is called

Answer (score 0):

if you start activity c from b and b from a if you use the back button on your phone at activity c it will go to b and back button press in b it will show a. if you use finish in all the 3 activities what happens is a calls b and a is finished and b calls c and b is finished so when you use finish in c it will not have b to show. so you have to tell where you are placing your finish based on some condition or a button click or just before starting a new activity, post your code and we will help you.